# how to improve speed of ajax response in jquery autocompletor

Tags: php, performance, jquery

I have implemented Jquery  autocompleter with PHP. I noticed that when I type a letter it takes more than 2 seconds to give the result. Is there way to increase the response speed? Can we use application caching in PHP?

If you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: Hi, bring all the data and put it on DOM. use that data to to auto complete

Comment: Sometimes, autocompletion data is just too large to do that.

Comment: @Srihari Goud, you mean at the page load, we get data from database and put it DOM right? I have 900 people in my database, I think that will be a problem as cuewizchris mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to search using autocomplete is by giving minLength=3 or 4 so that it doesn't have to search the whole database simply which results in browser hanging and it also consumes time..

Answer (score 2):

Unless you haven't accidentally made some kind of mistake within the client side Javascript code, there's no other way to greatly accelerate response speeds than trying to improve the speed your server side script responds with.

The most efficient way of doing this (giving the best results in terms of speed) is unfortunately not quite trivial: Instead of getting results from the database each time the autocompleter fires, fetching the data from some kind of memory based cache, such as Memcached or Redis. This of course requires some kind of measure of keeping the cache consistent with data in the database, so your autocomplete doesn't return outdated results.

Comment: thanks for mentioning `Memcached and Redis`. I will check and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the browsers `localstorage` to save the data from your server once. Then each time you write something into you autocompletion field, you query this storage instead of your PHP script.

If you have a large dataset and don't want to load this into the `localstorage`, you could use `memcached` or `redis` to cache your database queries.

Furthermore you can cache your classes to reduce the generation time of your PHP script.

Comment: localstorage supports in HTML 5 supporting broswsers right. I will in to this idea.

Answer (score 0):

use pre-populated list.
check this plugin http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Here I can't store data in pre-populated list as the data is stored in database and it always keep updating.